# Questions about Minkowski metric and dilatation of time in accelerated frame

Tags: special-relativity

I have two questions :

The first one is one the Minkowski metric.

We say that this metric is the following :

$$ ds^2=c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$$

But doesn't this assume that our vectors are in the form :

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
t\\ 
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}$$

instead of :

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
ct\\ 
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}$$

(and in the last case, the metric would be : $ ds^2=1*dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$)

---

Other question :

I have the following "Rindler" metric :

$$ ds^2=-(1+a \xi)^2 d \tau^2 + d\xi^2 $$

I work in an accelerated frame.

I have a point at coordinate $\xi_s$ and one at $\xi_d$.

In my course we wrote that :

$$ \Delta \tau_d =\frac{1+a\xi_d}{1+a\xi_s} \Delta \tau_s$$

Where $\Delta \tau_d$ and $\Delta \tau_s$ are the proper time at $\xi_s$ and $\xi_d$ but I don't understand how we get this.

Answer (score 3):

I find the use of $\tau$ in the Rindler metric a little confusing since we normally use $\tau$ for proper time. I generally write the Rindler metric as:

$$ c^2d\tau^2 = \left(1 + \frac{a}{c^2}x \right)^2 c^2 dt^2 - dx^2 $$

The $t$ and $x$ are the coordinates used by the observer at the origin with proper acceleration $a$. So if that observer measures a time interval at a fixed distance $x$, so $dx=0$, the metric gives us the proper time $d\tau$ elapsed at $x$:

$$ d\tau(x) = \left(1 + \frac{a}{c^2}x \right)dt $$

If you do this at two distances $x_1$ and $x_2$ this then gives you:

$$ \frac{d\tau(x_1)}{d\tau(x_2)} = \frac{1 + \frac{a}{c^2}x_1}{1 + \frac{a}{c^2}x_2} $$

Which is the equation you have.

Re your question about the Minkowski metric, if you use the coordinates $(t, x, y, z)$, where $t$ is the time recorded on your clock, then the metric is:

$$ ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 $$

Or you can do a (simple) coordinate transformation $T = ct$ in which case the metric expressed in the new coordinates is:

$$ ds^2 = -dT^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 $$

The two metrics are different because you're writing them in different coordinate systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the Rindler metric, how do you know that it is the proper time that you wrote on the lhs of your equality (where I have written $ds^2$, you wrote $d\tau^2$). I am not very familiar with special relativity yet so my question might be obvious.

Comment: @user3183950: have a look at my answer to [Confusion on Proper time and Proper Length](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316249/confusion-on-proper-time-and-proper-length/316252#316252) as it addresses exactly this point.